# how to handle network exception using coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I try handling exception using coroutine. I wrote code like this, but didn't work. I can't see any log except for using try-catch. I do not want to use try catch at all function, but want to make clean code handling exception. what should I do for this?

*viewmodel*

```
    private val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        when (exception) {
            is UnknownHostException -> {
               showLog("login UnknownHostException : " +exception.message)
            }
            else -> {

            }
        }
    }

    fun login(mobile:String){
        viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
            try{
               var login = apiRepository.login(mobile)
               _isLogin.value = login
            }catch(e:Exception){
            }
        }
    }
```

*repository*

```
    override suspend fun login(mobile: String): LoginResultData {
        var result =LoginResultData()
        withContext(ioDispatcher){
            val request = apiServerModel.login(mobile)
            val response = request.await()
            result = response
        }
        return  result
    }
```

Comment: I solved this. I  had to use this handler getting out of try-catch.

Comment: please add your own solution then

Comment: If you catch the exception and ignore it, why would you expect the `CoroutineExceptionHandler` to handle it? This isn't what `CoroutineExceptionHandler` is intended for (last-resort mechanism) and I don't think you should use it. "If you need to handle exception in a specific part of the code, it is recommended to use try/catch" ([Kotlin docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-exception-handler/))

Comment: You ate all the Exception in the launch, so are not propagated to exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun login(mobile:String){
    viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
        val login = apiRepository.login(mobile)
        _isLogin.value = login
    }
}
```